# Promise not waiting to resolve before next then

Tags: javascript, promise

**Code:**

```
var x = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout( function() {
        console.log( 'x done' );
        resolve()
    }, 1000 );
});


Promise.resolve().then(x).then((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log( 'all done' );
});
```

**Output:**

```
all done
x done
```

**Expected output:**

```
x done
all done
```

Why is the promise `x` not waiting to resolve before calling the next `then` callback?

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/puhbqtu0/1/

Comment: `then` expects a function as its argument, not a promise.

Comment: because `then()` needs a function as argument, not  a promise. So, the  next `then` is executed  after x is run, not resolved.

Comment: You should return `x` in `then`: `then(() => x)`.

Comment: Did you mean `x.then(() => console.log('all done'));`?

Comment: @AlexanderMac - can you write that up as an answer. Will choose it. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderMac: Not really. He either should drop `Promise.resolve()`, should *create* the `x` promise inside of that `then` callback, or should use `Promise.all` to wait for the timeout and the `Promise.resolve()`.

Comment: @Bergi I agree about `Promise.resolve()`, it's not required there, but what about `x`, why it can't be created out of the `then` callback? `x` can be external function for example or even variable - as result of a call another promise.

Comment: Why does it wait to resolve the promise and directly starts executing the code of 'All done' even if function is not supplied as handlers but promise ? Is this documented somewhere about this behaviour ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So as you want to run promises in a series you should convert `x` to function and call it in `then`:

```
function x() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('x done');
      resolve()
    }, 1000);
  });
});

Promise.resolve()
  .then(x)
  .then(() => console.log('all done'));
```

or simplest variant:

```
x().then(() => console.log('all done'));
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/puhbqtu0/4)

Comment: That's likely to be an antipattern which might end up with unhandled rejections. You shouldn't inject promises into a chain like that.

Comment: @Bergi - what do you suggest for running promises in a series?

Comment: @Bergi please clarify why it's bad.

Comment: To run them in series, you'd need to call the `setTimeout` from that `then(() => …)` callback, e.g. by wrapping `x` in a factory function. Currently `Promise.resolve()` and `x` are concurrent (and if you want that, you'd better use `Promise.all`).

Comment: Or convert `x` to function and call it in `then`.

Comment: My actual scenario requires that I run these functions in a series. What if there's another `y` function - so my last promise looks like `Promise.resolve().then(()=>x).then(()=>y).then((resolve, reject) => { console.log( 'all done' ); }})`

Comment: if you want to run them in series, convert `x` and `y` to function and call so: `x().then(y)`, `Promise.resolve` is not required there.

Comment: @AlexanderMac - Will the `x` function need to return a promise in that case?

Comment: Yes of course, the first function must create a promise chain, besides of this if the function doesn't return the promise, the next `then` starts immediately.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/puhbqtu0/1/ - tried that here, but when returning the promise without a callback, it's returned immediately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110382/discussion-between-hydera-and-alexander-mac).

Comment: @AlexanderMac - jsfiddle.net/puhbqtu0/1 - tried that here, but when returning the promise without a callback, it's returned immediately.
returning the promise correctly here - but y is now executed immediately, how do I make y wait ?